# How send GET request with value of parameter containing a space?

Tags: java, http, get-request

I'm testing this code below to send GET request with parameters and this code fails when the value of parameter is a string containing a space, Ex: `http://company.com/example.php?value=Jhon 123`. Already if i send `Jhon123` (withou any space) works fine.

Why this happens?

```
private static void sendGet(String site, String params) throws Exception {

        site += params;
        URL obj = new URL(site);

        try {

            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

            // optional default is GET
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + site);
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            //print result
            System.out.println(response.toString());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

    }
```

Comment: you can use a lot of encode decode method on queryString, urlencode is the easiest which follow browser standard but may some times fail, base64 is a better approach if you data is not too large in scale

Comment: @PSo, thank you. `URLEncoder` was the solution to this my trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should [URL Encode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) your request.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `URLEncoder` to encode your parameter:

```
String url = "http://company.com/example.php?value=" + URLEncoder.encode("Jhon 123", "utf-8");
```